# Linux: memory usage summary for program

Tags: linux, trace, proc

I need some command line utility able to run specified command and measure process group memory usage at peak and average (RSS, virtual and shared). As I understand that should be a combination of ptrace(2) and libprocps, but I can't find anything similar.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/usr/bin/time -f "max RSS: %MKb" <command>
```

See man time for more details.

Comment: Also I've found valgrind tool massif, but time solution is much simpler.